# Android Studio cannot resolve symbols and recognise packages

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I've been trying to get an app running on Android Studio for a couple of days but no results so far.
When running the app it gets up to
[1000 errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH8Eb.png)
in the project,
[like imports from react-native, symbols and some other stuff.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mONkb.png)

I have downloaded the project, installed the packages with 'yarn install', imported and made the configurations on Android Studio, installed the necessary tools so I can use the app (jdk, sdk, etc) but nothing seems to going smoothly, already hate it.

- Android Studio Version:  Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Canary 11
- SDK 28.0.3
- Node: 16.4.0
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.60.4
- Anroid Gradle Plugin: 3.5.1
- Gradle Version: 5.4.1
- Gradle JDK: 11.0.11

build.grandle:

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 23
    //        googlePlayServicesVersion = "17.0.2"
    compileSdkVersion = "28"
    targetSdkVersion = "28"
    supportLibVersion = '1.0.2'
    mediaCompatVersion = '1.0.1'
    supportV4Version = '1.0.0'
      }
       repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
      }
     dependencies {
    classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1')

    }
  }

       allprojects {
       repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
    }
    maven {
        // Android JSC is installed from npm
        url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
    }

    google()
    jcenter()
      }
    }

         subprojects {
     afterEvaluate { project ->
    if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 28
            buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

            lintOptions {
                abortOnError false
            }
        }
    }
   }
  }
```

ERRORS:
[CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePxUl.png)
[image: moar]
C:\Users\senchev\Desktop\workpls\allexc-app-react-native\allexc-app-react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\async-storage\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\asyncstorage\AsyncStoragePackage.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
public List createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
^
symbol:   class ViewManager
location: class AsyncStoragePackage

[here's more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40qSQ.png)

I have tried:

1. Installing different versions of SDK, JDK, grandle, Android Studio
2. Syncing project with grade files (a thousand times)
3. Deleting .idea & .grandle folder.
4. Build > clean & rebuild
5. Invalidate cache and restart(including the clear file system cache and local history)
   and maybe some other things but I can't seem to rememeber.

Same errors appear when I have tried all those things.

I thought it was a problem with the library but they are imported and I'm really confused...

help

Comment: most likely, it's issues with syntax, but since you didn't provide any of the code you've written, nor shown the actual errors, there's not much we can say

Comment: @Slavi Enchev ,  add your gradle code here so we help you.  and top right side of your image click on "17" -- this is shows error comes in program.

Comment: @Stultuske I have updated the question, hope it's what you've asked for. Thank you so much for replying.

Comment: @MAYUR SANCHETI I have updated it for you too, I appreciate your answer.